# Using Angular ng-class twice inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

Is it possible to use `ng-class` twice inside `ng-repeat`? once to `highlight` a row selected `row` and one to check `object` propeties:

```
<ul>
      <li
        ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-class="{'someclass' : item.Id > 10 && item.color != 'red'}" ng-class = "'selected' : $index == selected">
        {{item .name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

for some reason the second `ng-class`(in this example `selectd`) is not working.
The items:

```
 $scope.items = [

    { Id: 1, name: "item1" , color : 'red' },
    { Id: 20, name: "item1" , color : 'blue' },
    { Id: 11, name: "item1" , color : 'white' }
 ];
```

Comment: @KhalidHussain thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put both in one ng-class - something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li
    ng-repeat="item in items"
    ng-class="{'someclass' : item.Id > 10 && item.color != 'red', 'selected' : $index == selected}">
    {{item .name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks.